# hide the default resize grip in wpf

Tags: wpf, resizegrip

I have a borderless and transparent window in WPF, with some fancy decoration at the bottom. There's a custom footer with some non conventional curves and what not showing the company logo. This window needs to be resizable with a grip in the bottom right corner like conventional windows.

Anyways, I have put my own ResizeGrip in a place that is actually on the footer, however the default grip still shows up and it's floating in space due to the invisible window.

How do I hide the default ResizeGrip?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The appearance of a resize grip is controlled via the [ResizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode.aspx) dependency property on the Window.

If this is set to CanResizeWithGrip:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="50" Width="150" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="#19FFFFFF"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    <Grid></Grid>
</Window>
```

The Window will look like this:

[image: With Grip]

If it is set to CanResize (the default):

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="50" Width="150" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="#19FFFFFF"
        ResizeMode="CanResize">
    <Grid></Grid>
</Window>
```

The Window will look as follows:

[image: Can Resize]

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus I added some new ones.

Answer (score 18):

So to hide the default grip, I overwrote the default ResizeGrip style such that it's visibility is hidden. Easy with the help of Expression Blend 2.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ResizeGrip}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ResizeGrip}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</Style>
```

Then I set up my own ResizeGrip on my custom window decoration with a style that is identical to the default grip style.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ResizeGripperForeground" Color="#B8B4A2"/>
<Style x:Key="VisibleResizeGrip" TargetType="{x:Type ResizeGrip}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ResizeGrip}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Path Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Data="M 8,0 L 10,0 L 10,2 L 8,2 Z M 4,4 L 6,4 L 6,6 L 4,6 Z M 8,4 L 10,4 L 10,6 L 8,6 Z M 0,8 L 2,8 L 2,10 L 0,10 Z M 4,8 L 6,8 L 6,10 L 4,10 Z M 8,8 L 10,8 L 10,10 L 8,10 Z"/>
                    <Path Fill="{StaticResource ResizeGripperForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,3,3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Data="M 8,0 L 10,0 L 10,2 L 8,2 Z M 4,4 L 6,4 L 6,6 L 4,6 Z M 8,4 L 10,4 L 10,6 L 8,6 Z M 0,8 L 2,8 L 2,10 L 0,10 Z M 4,8 L 6,8 L 6,10 L 4,10 Z M 8,8 L 10,8 L 10,10 L 8,10 Z"/>
        <Path Data="M8,0L10,0 10,2 8,2z M4,4L6,4 6,6 4,6z M8,4L10,4 10,6 8,6z M0,8L2,8 2,10 0,10z M4,8L6,8 6,10 4,10z M8,8L10,8 10,10 8,10z" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <Path Data="M8,0L10,0 10,2 8,2z M4,4L6,4 6,6 4,6z M8,4L10,4 10,6 8,6z M0,8L2,8 2,10 0,10z M4,8L6,8 6,10 4,10z M8,8L10,8 10,10 8,10z" Fill="{StaticResource ResizeGripperForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,3,3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
      </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```